# When opening google picker window in IE save and cancel buttons become unresponsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

I have implemented the google picker APi which is working fine in all browsers but on IE 11 after the modal window is opened the save and cancel buttons become unresponsive and the only way to make them work again is to click in another window or thing and return to the browser